# Getting 407 on webdriver update when desktop was accessed thru RDC

Tags: webdriver, protractor

My machine is currently experiencing issue that requires re-installation of NPM (+webdriver-manager) whenever the machine restarted or when webdriver-manager window was closed.

I was able to update webdriver-manager by using the line below:

```
webdriver-manager --ignore_ssl update --ie32
```

Since I am working on a different location, I can only access the machine thru Remote Desktop Connection and when I try to use the same line, I am getting the error below:

```
C:\Windows\System32>webdriver-manager --ignore_ssl update --ie32
[10:32:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[10:32:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[10:32:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[10:32:27] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\ng66ed6\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:166:19)
    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
```

Any suggestion or possible workaround is very much appreciated. :)

Note: Node.js CMD was run as admin